# How to comment a portion of a line of code in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to comment only a portion of a line of code. So I would select the portion and then execute a macro that will insert a `/*` and `*/` before and after the selected portion respectively. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `Toggle Block Comment` command (`editor.action.blockComment`)

[image: Toggle block comment in a typescript file]

Note that `Toggle Block Comment` is a language aware command, so it will use the correct comment block type for the current language. In html files for example, it uses `<!--` and `-->`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) vscode extension

Write the following code in the `settings.json`

```
"macros" : {
    "commentPortion": [
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        {
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
            "when": "editorTextFocus",
            "args": {
                "snippet": "/*${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}*/ $0"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

And then in `keybindings.json` add the following:

```
  {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+]",
   "command": "macros.commentPortion",
   "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
```